# When designing icons for iOS with vectors, how do I export to the various sizes?

Tags: ios

I've been told to design iOS icons with vectors, so you can scale to all the different necessary sizes really easily. So I used Sketch 2 (I also have a copy of Illustrator handy) to create an app icon totally comprised of vectors that can scale to any resolution.

However, I'm not sure how I export it to all these different resolutions. What do I do from here? Save it as an .SVG and do something in Illustrator?

If it helps, I created a 200x200 rounded rectangle base for the icon, which is the "size" of it, but again, as it's vector it can scale to any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS does not read SVG outside of its UIWebView unfortunately (it would be really cool if it did).
Just export your svg as png or jpg in all the sizes you need and then load the right one for each device in your code. For example for iPad retina you want 70x70 jpg if the icon has to be 35x35 points big.

Another, more efficient, way is to just draw your icons programmatically with Core Graphics, so you don't have to load a different icon for each size, and your icons won't look different in future devices with different pixel densities. You can do it manually, or with an app named PaintCode, which is pricey ($99) but very useful: you draw and it generates the code for you to put in the drawrect method.

Comment: PaintCode is very interesting, I'll look into it for sure. In the meantime, however, how do I do the exporting of these vectors to the different sizes? It seems the only option is .SVG or .PNG (which I want), but with .PNG it's only at the current canvas size, with no option to scale it.

Comment: I don't own Sketch 2 but you could just change the canvas size before each export. Or open the svg in illustrator and export it from there.

Comment: I have inkscape which is the open source equivalent of illustrator and it supports exporting for different pixel densities.. If everything else fails, you can download that for free and open the svg/ export from there

Comment: I'm very confused how to export it even in Illustrator. I'll give Inkscape a try too.

Comment: to open it in illustrator you just need to open the svg file you saved.  Once you open it I am sure there is an export option in the menu. In inkscape you do File -> export bitmap..